# Does anyone know this encoding?

Tags: file-format, encodings

There is an interesting article on Phack:
http://phrack.org/issues/69/15.html#article

At the end of the article there is the source appended in a strange encoding.

```
begin 664 hypervisor_for_rootkit.tar.gz
M'XL(`%?BS58``^P];7>B2-;]U3ZG_P/K[LXQTU$!$<R0S!Q4['C&1!\U[<PS
M/<=%*)5I!`8P+],[_WUO%:!@0,U+)YUNJF,+U*U;5??]E@7,;VSD7.JNY8RG
M\'$LR_NH>^57CUEH*`)-XV]&J,:^P_**87F^4N$96A!>T0S'5/A75/511Y%2
...
`
end
```

Does anyone know how to convert this back to the original archive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be [UUencoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) data.

Comment: I succeeded decode it with perl: the format is "u61". put the string into $a and: open(my $out, '>:raw', 'b1.tar.gz') or die "Unable to open: $!";
print $out unpack("u61",$a);
close($out);

Comment: Append: there happen to be a program to decode as well:  "uudecode"

Answer (score 4):

Guntram Blohm seems to be right. But in the spirit of "give a man a fish and he has food for one day", magic mime is an easy way to figure out most formats. The `file` command detects filetypes by their "magic" mime, i.e. markers left in the file (like you see `%PDF` in PDFs and `PK` in zip files).

`file` accepts as argument a filename, like `file /tmp/unknown-file`. It can also read from STDIN if you use `-` as the "file" argument. This makes it easy to just figure out an encoding you're seeing without having to store the file:

```
cat | file -
```

Now paste the data and end with Ctrl+D (which signals 'end of input'). In your case, the result is this:

```
/dev/stdin: uuencoded or xxencoded, ASCII text
```

For some formats it can give a lot of information, like for gzip compressed data:

```
echo test | gzip | file -
/dev/stdin: gzip compressed data, last modified: Wed Oct 19 01:36:02 2016, from Unix
```

Comment: Also, if you add `-z`, it will look inside compressed files, giving you even more information

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a file manager like Total Commander on Windows, simply create a new text file (Shift+F4), name it like you want followed by `.uue` extension
i.e. `hypervisor_for_rootkit.tar.gz.uue`

Then paste the whole encoded symbols in that new text file with `*.uue` extension including the `'begin ...'` and `'end'` strings.

Now open (click) that file in Total Commander and it'll be ready to unpack (decode) it to the sidebar location.

Or Files -> Decode File... in menu on selected .uue file